# Sometimes my deleted data does not seems to be executed directly with Entity Frmaework

Tags: entity-framework, entity

I use Entity Framework. I need to perform an ajax delete and immediately after that an ajax get.

Sometimes, the data is 'really' deleted then the get take it into account.

Sometimes the data is not 'already' deleted and thus the get is not what I expect for.

Is there a way to 'flush' someway to force the database to be directly updated when a delete occured?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE

```
public class VehicleContext : DbContext
{
    public VehicleContext()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<VehicleModel> Vehicles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried rolling your delete command / action in a transaction?

Comment: Limit the lifetime of `ObjectContext/DbContext` to single request.

Comment: Thanks but how to preceed? I updated my question to show you my DbContext

Comment: What you haven't shown is the lifetime of the INSTANCE of the DbContext, just the definition of the context. After you call SaveChanges, dispose the context instance and create a new one. You do need to call Save before fetching to force the deletion to take effect.

Comment: The problem was in my code: I do 2 ajax calls and the 2nd call was not waiting for the 1qst one to complete before executing. I modified my code to do the 2nd call in the onsuccess event of the 1st call.